# how to take the print out in a paper having size 1/4 of actual a4 size paper

Tags: c#

I am doing a project in c#. I need to take the print out in a paper having size 1/4 of actual a4 size paper. How can I do this via c# code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did any research prior to asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly easy to use tutorial to print in c# can be found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c%23/).

Also, 1/4th of A4 is A6 format. See image.

[image]